# How to prevent Command Buttons and Comments from being deleted?

Tags: vba, excel

The below code worked when I was using a Form Control button, but I have updated my sheet to use a Command Button to use a User Form. The below code will remove both the Command Button and any comments. Is there a way to have it only delete pictures? or to limit its effective range to `Range("A3:A1002")`? or a way to exclude Command Button/Comments from the code?

```
Private Sub Remove_Images_Click()
'Remove Images
    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Dim shp         As Shape
    Dim picArray()  As String
    Dim index       As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 
    Columns(1).Replace What:="No Picture Found", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    index = 1
    For Each shp In wks.Shapes

        If shp.Type <> msoFormControl Then
            ReDim Preserve picArray(1 To index)
            picArray(index) = shp.Name
            index = index + 1
        End If
    Next shp
    wks.Shapes.Range(picArray).Delete
ExitRoutine:
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set shp = Nothing
    Erase picArray
    ECT_Image_Template.Hide
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Prompt:="Unable to find photo", _
           Title:="An error occured", _
           Buttons:=vbExclamation
    Resume ExitRoutine
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the the brightness property to delete only the pictures:

```
Private Sub Remove_Images_Click()
'Remove Images
    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Dim shp         As Shape
    Dim picArray()  As String
    Dim count       As Integer
    Dim bightness   As Variant

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    columns(1).Replace What:="No Picture Found", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    ReDim picArray(0 To wks.shapes.count)

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each shp In wks.shapes
        bightness = shp.PictureFormat.Brightness
        If bightness Then
          bightness = Empty
          picArray(count) = shp.Name
          count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If count Then
      ReDim Preserve picArray(0 To count - 1)
      wks.shapes.Range(picArray).Delete
    End If

ExitRoutine:
    ECT_Image_Template.Hide
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox Prompt:="Unable to find photo", _
           Title:="An error occured", _
           Buttons:=vbExclamation
    Resume ExitRoutine
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I removed the first `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` on my copy as I feel this was a typo.

Comment: using `ìf shp.type= 13  then` , would be more appropriate. Also using `wks.shapes.Range(picArray).Delete` looks faster, but i had cases where it throwed mistakes, so i had to delete them one by one instead, wich isn't slow if using `application.screenupdating=false`.